# Here Maps roundabout icon

Tags: ios, here-api

I have to calculate the angle of exit in a roundabout (relative to a point of entry) to display the appropriate icon during turn-by-turn navigation.

I'm using the `angle` property of a `NMAManeuver` with roundabout as turn type, but angle values are not what I'm expecting. As an example for a maneuver in the linked image I've an angle of 1° and a map orientation of 163° (`orientation` of map view and `mapOrientation` of the maneuver are the same) but the roundabout exit is at around 270°.

Is there something to take into account during calculation?

[image: Screenshot of map directions]

Answer (score 0):

Angle is the correct property to Maneuver.Angle to calculate the angle of exit. you can also try getTurn() which gets the Maneuver.Turn required to complete the maneuver.

For detailed reference, please refer :

- http://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html
- http://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Maneuver.html

Comment: I am also trying to figure out how to use the angle on the roundabout. I do not find any correlation between the angle and the direction of turning. Are these angles only related to the direction or also to the number of exits. Sometimes to go straight I get an angle of 261 degrees